# div doesn't stay populated when called inside callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io

I'm trying to fill an html div with data requested from a backend server with the help of socket.io.

```
socket.on('solution response', function(solution) {
    console.log(solution)
    $('#answersheet').text(solution)
})
```

I know that I'm getting the solution from the backend server because I can see it in the console log. And sometimes the html div populates but only for a fraction of a second so I think this may be a problem of persistence. What's stopping me from filling my div?

Comment: Is it possible that subsequent messages from the server are causing you to overwrite the `div`'s text with an empty string?

Comment: If that script is running on the server *before* the page renders, then `$('#answersheet')` may not exist at the time this function runs. Try to `console.log($('#answersheet'))` in your function and see if the element exists.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're missing ; ?

```
    socket.on('solution response', function(solution) {
      console.log(solution);
      $('#answersheet').text(solution);
    })
```

Comment: Semicolons are not required